# Can I append vertexes to a default buffer using UpdateSubresources?

Tags: c++, direct3d, vertex-buffer, direct3d12

The documentation for `UpdateSubresources` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/updatesubresources3). The parameter descriptions are so minimal that they aren't very helpful to someone using the function for the first time (like me).

```cpp
UINT64 inline UpdateSubresources(
  _In_ ID3D12GraphicsCommandList *pCmdList,
  _In_ ID3D12Resource            *pDestinationResource,
  _In_ ID3D12Resource            *pIntermediate,
       UINT64                    IntermediateOffset,
  _In_ UINT                      FirstSubresource,
  _In_ UINT                      NumSubresources,
  _In_ D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA    *pSrcData
);
```

I'm trying to follow [these code examples](https://github.com/d3dcoder/d3d12book) from the book *Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 12*.

I created a vertex buffer and I want to "draw" on the touchscreen and add triangles to that buffer. The buffer creation is in these functions below, copied from the book code, basically. The `size` argument there is a big enough to hold say 10000 vertexes. Let's assume for now I'm not running out of space in the buffer. I'm just trying to update it with new `Vertex` data that comes in.

```
com_ptr<ID3D12Resource> create_default_buffer(ID3D12Device* device, uint64_t size) {
    com_ptr<ID3D12Resource> buffer;

    CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heap_props(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    auto res_desc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(size);
    auto hr = device->CreateCommittedResource(&heap_props, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &res_desc, 
                                              D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON,
                                              nullptr, __uuidof(buffer), buffer.put_void());
    check_hresult(hr);
    return buffer;
}

com_ptr<ID3D12Resource> create_upload_buffer(ID3D12Device* device, uint64_t size) {
    com_ptr<ID3D12Resource> buffer;

    CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heap_props(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD);
    auto res_desc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(size);
    auto hr = device->CreateCommittedResource(&heap_props, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &res_desc,
                                              D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ, // ??
                                              nullptr, __uuidof(buffer), buffer.put_void());
    check_hresult(hr);
    return buffer;
}
```

Now lets say I have some new `Vertex` data in a `std::vector<Vertex>` that I want to append to the buffers? How do I use `UpdateSubresources` to do that? Is that possible, or does `UpdateSubresources` only overwrite the entire buffer?

Comment: Engineer-driven Documentation: Documentation that's only understandable to those who designed the system. This is why a good technical writer is such an asset. They don't know how the system works and won't make the same sort of assumptions about what the userbase needs to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpdateSubresources` is an inline function, you can see its source code in `d3dx12_resource_helpers.h`.

You can see that for buffers, `UpdateSubresources` eventually calls `CopyBufferRegion`, with the `DstOffset` argument hard-coded to `0`.

```
if (DestinationDesc.Dimension == D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER)
{
    pCmdList->CopyBufferRegion(
        pDestinationResource, 0, pIntermediate,
        pLayouts[0].Offset, pLayouts[0].Footprint.Width);
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

So the answer is no, it's not possible to append data to the buffers using this function, it will always overwrite the entire buffer. But you can implement your own using `CopyBufferRegion`.